# Incorrect path with function getcwd()

Tags: python, path, getcwd

I get the wrong path back. The Datafile is in D:... and get everytime the path C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xy back from python. I use the function

```
path = getcwd()
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Use `setcwd` to set the working directory to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Okay the would be an option, but i don´t want to set. I want to read the path, because i won´t be change it in all Datafiles again.

Comment: getcwd gets the current path that your process is operating in - like when you cd into a directory in a terminal. If you tells us more about why you want to do this, we can probably be more help. E.g. what do you need the path for?

Comment: Where are you executing your script? If you are executing yor script in D:\... then the `getcwd` function will return that path. You're either executing the script from another location or executing a module in your C:\Python27\... directory which is calling `getcwd`.

Comment: I need the current file to list file in the folder. I got a unknown number of files in the folder. My idea is, to put the python file in the folder in list me up for the following functions of the script.

Comment: I did´nt know my mistake, now it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be executing the script in a different place than your intended directory.

**Solution 1:** Move the .py file to the target directory, and execute it there.

- Pros:

  - Easy
  - Works cross-platform (and for other users - if you do this, use getcwdu for Unicode)
  - No hard-coded path strings
- Cons:

  - File must be in the same or higher directory as target folder

**Solution 2:** Manually write the string of the path to the folder.

- Pros:

  - 'Just Works'
- Cons:

  - Annoying bugs w/typos
  - Need to re-code every time you change directories
  - Won't work anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

In my idea, make sure your IDE has your target directory opened as your project folder.
After all, it's a debug-time error, and won't affect the smooth running of your program in the runtime, if your program's launch script has the right address for your program to run, and does its part normally!
By the way @order, I'm totally against hardcoding a path into your code, because it's just a very lame programming exercise!
Just get yourselves used to going through the right exercise, although it doesn't seem very beneficial in the short run. in the coming years of your career, you're going to be against using the cons and pros of such a comparison, but it will become a right or wrong coding exercise!
Cheers.